# Flask/Thread. Мне нужно написать параллельную функцию которая будет раз в день чистить просроченные записи в бд

Tags: python, многопоточность, flask

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]**Мне нужно написать функцию которая будет раз в день чистить просроченные записи в бд
***Проблема состоит в том что SQLAchemy должен видеть app чтобы работать с базой данных, но как мне в мой thread передать переменную app из главной функции,*

```
def threaded_task():
    while True:
        with app.app_context():
            Link.query.filter(Link.expiration_date < date.today()).delete()
            time.sleep(86400)

def create_app(config_file='settings.py'):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_pyfile(config_file)

    db.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(short)

    thread = Thread(target=threaded_task)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    return app
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def threaded_task(app):
...

thread = Thread(target=threaded_task, args=(app,))
```

Только обратите внимание, что аргументы нужно передавать именно в виде кортежа, поэтому запятая после `app` обязательна, иначе это будет уже не кортеж.

Но вообще лучше такие задачи вешать на шедулер, вешать задачи, подходящие больше для шедулера, на веб-сервис - совершенно неправильная практика. Веб-сервер по своей природе такая штука, которая может быть в любой момент перезагружена. И у неё ограниченное число рабочих потоков. Вешайте такие задачи лучше на системный шедулер, он должен сработать по расписанию в почти любых обстоятельствах. Он не будет тратить на себя поток и сработает правильно даже если сервер перезагрузят.